# Angular.js Routing Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

**EDIT: For everyone interested: I solved the issue by adding the base tag to the head of the html file.**

I am trying to get a test app with single page routing to work. After some research I couldn't find any hint online on what I might be missing.

Here's my code: (Any ideas?)

```js
// public/js/app.js

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'DashboardCtrl']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        })

        .when('/test',{
            templateUrl: 'views/testTemplate.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="js/controllers/DashboardCtrl.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="DashboardController">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>

    <a href="/test">Testing</a>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
// public/js/controllers/DashboardCtrl.js
angular.module('DashboardCtrl', []).controller('DashboardController', function($scope) {

    // todo

});
```

App.js is being run (breakpoints in the browser show). I also tried the hrefs "#test", "#!test", "#!/test". None worked. Might be a typo that I don't find :)

EDIT
Created a plunker here: https://embed.plnkr.co/L7PSkNPoxSO7shtRx5JZ/

Comment: In your snippet, dashboardCtrl.js is showing 404 not found. Can you try some plunker or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use routing and load controllers/views dynamically, you don't need `ng-controller` here: `<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="DashboardController">`, it will be loaded dynamically depending on your route config and current route.

And didn't you forget to declare views for your controllers to see any changes on route change?

Comment: @EmanuelMetzenthin, and didn't you forget to declare views for your controllers to see any changes on route change? `views/dashboard.html` and `views/testTemplate.html` are not empty?

Comment: They exist. I just didn't post them in the question

Comment: @EmanuelMetzenthin, if you will create working jsfiddle or plunker, it will be easier to debug ;)

Comment: @EmanuelMetzenthin, do you have a server-side for your Angularjs app?

Comment: Yes, I do. It simply serves the index file and doesn't do much else